# Working out how many records are in a database or dataset in vb

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am currently working on a project where I need to know how many records are in a single table in a database as the number of records changes dependent on inputs made by the user. Is there any way to program a function that will work out the number of records is my database?

Here is the code I have at current which isn't working.

```
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;"
    TheDatabase = "/TeachersData.mdb"
    FullDatabasePath = CurDir() & TheDatabase
    dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()
    NoOfRecords = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teachers"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Teachers"

    RecordNumbers = New OleDbDataAdapter(NoOfRecords, con)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "TeachersData")

    con.Close()
End Sub

Sub VerifyDetails()
    For i = 0 To Len(RecordNumbers)
        If Initials.Text = ds.Tables("TeachersData").Rows(i).Item(1) Then
            Salt = ds.Tables("TeachersData").Rows(i).Item(3)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Records are spread in different tables. Do you want to sum the record count of every single table in your database?

Comment: No, just from a single table

Comment: Then you need a query like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTableName. Did you have made any effort to solve your problem (I mean code to see and help you on that)

Comment: Added current code

Comment: Why not write your SQL as a query in the Access DB and `SELECT` the count from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making some confusion with two OleDbDataAdapters. You prepare one with the correct query (RecordNumbers) but then you fill another one (da).
But you really don't need any OleDbDataAdapter for this. Just an OleDbCommand to execute

```
con.Open()
Dim cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Teachers", con)
Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Now count contains the number of records present in the Teachers table.

Comment: Works Perfectly Thanks